# add correct Bundle order for Intent in Zebra Datawedge app

Tags: android, zebra-printers

I've developed an android app with a Zebra RS5100 finger scanner. So far the scanner was paired with the device and then I opened the "Datawedge" manually to enable codabar with minimumlength 4 and maximum length 20.

According to the docs

https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/6-9/guide/api/setconfig/

it is possible to set 'decoder_codabar', 'decoder_codabar_length1' and 'decoder_codabar_length2' in a Bundle + Intent.

What is the correct list of bundles with their settings to pass to SendBroadcast ? The following code enables a profile in the datawedge and sets scanner input enabled. But deeper than that there are no examples.
Should I create a new Bundle and add that to the bParams Bundle or add settings to the bParams Bundle itself?

```
public static Intent Init()
{
    Bundle bMain = new Bundle();

    bMain.PutString("PROFILE_NAME", "SorterApp");
    bMain.PutString("PROFILE_ENABLED", "true");
    bMain.PutString("CONFIG_MODE", "UPDATE");

    Bundle bConfig = new Bundle();
    bConfig.PutString("PLUGIN_NAME", "BARCODE");
    bConfig.PutString("RESET_CONFIG", "false");

    Bundle bParams = new Bundle();
    bParams.PutString("scanner_input_enabled", "true");

    bConfig.PutBundle("PARAM_LIST", bParams);

    bMain.PutBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", bConfig);

    // decoder_codabar ??????
    // decoder_i2of5 ????????
    // decoder_codabar_length1 ?????

    Intent dataWedgeIntent = new Intent();
    dataWedgeIntent.SetAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");
    dataWedgeIntent.PutExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG", bMain);

    return dataWedgeIntent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally figured it out, maybe someone finds a use for it someday.

Just adding

```
    barCodeProps.PutString("decoder_codabar_enabled", "true");
    barCodeProps.PutString("decoder_codabar_length1", "3");
```

is not enough.
It only works after adding scanner_selection auto to the bundle.

```
barCodeProps.PutString("scanner_selection", "auto");
```

Here is the full function

```
    public static Intent Init()
    {
        Bundle profileConfig = new Bundle();

        profileConfig.PutString("PROFILE_NAME", "RopsSorterApp");
        profileConfig.PutString("PROFILE_ENABLED", "true");
        profileConfig.PutString("CONFIG_MODE", "OVERWRITE");

        Bundle barCodeConfig = new Bundle();
        barCodeConfig.PutString("PLUGIN_NAME", "BARCODE");
        barCodeConfig.PutString("RESET_CONFIG", "true");

        Bundle barCodeProps = new Bundle();
        barCodeProps.PutString("scanner_selection", "auto");
        barCodeProps.PutString("scanner_input_enabled", "true");

        barCodeProps.PutString("decoder_codabar_enabled", "true");
        barCodeProps.PutString("decoder_codabar_length1", "3");

        barCodeProps.PutString("decoder_i2of5", "true");
        barCodeProps.PutString("decoder_i2of5_length1", "3");

        barCodeConfig.PutBundle("PARAM_LIST", barCodeProps);            
        profileConfig.PutBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", barCodeConfig);

        Intent dataWedgeIntent = new Intent();
        dataWedgeIntent.SetAction("com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION");
        dataWedgeIntent.PutExtra("com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG", profileConfig);

        return dataWedgeIntent;
    }
```

Then broadcast the intent to the datawedge app.

```
SendBroadcast(AutoConfig.Init());
```

Beware that using OVERWRITE reset *all other settings*

```
bMain.PutString("CONFIG_MODE", "OVERWRITE");
```

If you dont want that use UPDATE

```
bMain.PutString("CONFIG_MODE", "UPDATE");
```